# How to access Json element with the name "long" and "short"

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, signed-integer

I am trying to access a json element with the name "long", but VS gives an error, it detects it as a 16 bit signed integer.
The other elements in Json I can access , except element "long" and  "short".
Is there a way around this?

```
var resultOpenPositions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(JsonopenPositions);
string ShrtLong = resultOpenPositions.positions[0].long.units; // long here gives error , vs detects it as a 16 bit signed integer

// Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse); 
    public class Long
    {
        public string averagePrice { get; set; }
        public string pl { get; set; }
        public string resettablePL { get; set; }
        public List<string> tradeIDs { get; set; }
        public string units { get; set; }
        public string unrealizedPL { get; set; }
    }

    public class Short
    {
        public string pl { get; set; }
        public string resettablePL { get; set; }
        public string units { get; set; }
        public string unrealizedPL { get; set; }
        public string averagePrice { get; set; }
        public List<string> tradeIDs { get; set; }
    }

    public class Position
    {
        public string instrument { get; set; }
        public Long @long { get; set; }
        public string pl { get; set; }
        public string resettablePL { get; set; }
        public Short @short { get; set; }
        public string unrealizedPL { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public string lastTransactionID { get; set; }
        public List<Position> positions { get; set; }
    }
```

here is the json part:

```
{
  "positions": [
    {
      "instrument": "EUR_USD",
      "long": {
        "units": "1",
        "averagePrice": "1.13093",
        "pl": "-1077.2255",
        "resettablePL": "-1077.2255",
        "financing": "-48.6223",
        "dividendAdjustment": "0.0000",
        "guaranteedExecutionFees": "0.0000",
        "tradeIDs": [
          "17800"
        ],
        "unrealizedPL": "-0.0001"
      },
      "short": {
        "units": "0",
        "pl": "-543.3196",
        "resettablePL": "-543.3196",
        "financing": "-3.1941",
        "dividendAdjustment": "0.0000",
        "guaranteedExecutionFees": "0.0000",
        "unrealizedPL": "0.0000"
      },
      "pl": "-1620.5451",
      "resettablePL": "-1620.5451",
      "financing": "-51.8164",
      "commission": "0.0000",
      "dividendAdjustment": "0.0000",
      "guaranteedExecutionFees": "0.0000",
      "unrealizedPL": "-0.0001",
      "marginUsed": "0.0333"
    }
  ],
  "lastTransactionID": "17800"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Prefix the call to the property name with an `@`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/):

> Keywords are predefined, reserved identifiers that have special meanings to the compiler. They cannot be used as identifiers in your program unless they include @ as a prefix. For example, @if is a valid identifier, but if is not because if is a keyword.

```
string ShrtLong = resultOpenPositions.positions[0].@long.units;
```

---

Alternativelly, configure the serializer to handle camel cased `json` elements while having `Pascal`  cased properties on your model.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the best way is to use [JsonProperty] attribute. And you don't need 2 classes Long and Short, it would be enough just one.

Code

```
var resultOpenPositions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root(JsonopenPositions);
string ShrtLong = resultOpenPositions.positions[0].longPosition.units;
```

classes

```
  public class Root
    {
        public string lastTransactionID { get; set; }
        public List<Position> positions { get; set; }
    }

    public class Position
    {   
        public string pl { get; set; }
        public string instrument { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("long")]
        public PositionPL longPosition { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("short")]
        public PositionPL shortPosition { get; set; }
        public string resettablePL { get; set; }
        public string unrealizedPL { get; set; }
    }

  public class PositionPL
    { 
        public string pl { get; set; }
        public string averagePrice { get; set; }
        public string resettablePL { get; set; }
        public List<string> tradeIDs { get; set; }
        public string units { get; set; }
        public string unrealizedPL { get; set; }
    }
```